# No viable conversion from 'Foo' to 'Foo *const' C++

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class that does an implementation of a graph (template class) in C++ (I didn't make this), and basically what I want to do is have a representation of Places (they are my vertices) and my edges (that link them) are distances (in miles).

I declared a simple `Graph<Places *, double> places;` and now I'm creating a method that checks check if a certain Place is already in the graph in order to avoid duplicates. My graph has a method `Vertice<TV,TR>* findvert_content(const TV& v) const;` that returns a pointer of an vertice it finds (so if that returning pointer is valid, I'm assuming it exists in the graph). Now I want to do this in my Test class:

```
bool Test::verifiesName(Place *place) { 
    Vertice<Place *, double> find_place = places.findvert_content(*place);
    ...
}
```

**The problem is it gives me an semantic issue: "No viable conversion from 'Place' to 'Place *const'" and I don't know what to do from here.**

Here is the code of my findvert method (for reference):

```
template<class TV,class TR>
Vertice<TV,TR>* Graph<TV,TR>::findvert_content(const TV& v) const
{
    Vertice<TV,TR>* ap=graf;

    while (ap != NULL)
    {
        if (ap->vcontent == v)
            return ap ;
        else 
            ap=ap->apvertice;
    }
    return ap;
}
```

P.S. graf is just an attribute in my Graph class: `Vertice<TV,TR>* graf;`.

Comment: Grammar note: The singular form of "Vertices" is "Vertex", not "Vertice".

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: No, that syntax is correct. places is not a pointer. As you can see above it's declared as Graph<Places *, double> places;

Comment: @Tudor whoops you're right, I confused `place` with `places`

Comment: @Nicol Bolas In English, yep, I just did a rough translation from variables that had different names in another language and I skipped that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*place` is the value at the address where `place` points to. Are you sure you want to pass the value and not the pointer itself when you call the method? Like:

```
Vertice<Place *, double> find_place = places.findvert_content(place);
```

Also, why do you need the & if you are not modifying `v` inside the method? Then declare

```
template<class TV,class TR>
Vertice<TV,TR>* Graph<TV,TR>::findvert_content(const TV v) const
```

and it should be compatible with the above call.

Comment: I changed the code and now it's `Vertice<Place *, double> *find_place = places.find_content(place);`. Apparently I had missed the * in the name of the object and had to remove, like you said, the * from the place argument. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't create the Graph template class (it's a college final project assignment) and I'm not allowed to change code that's already written in that class (only add methods to it). And I believe whoever wrote it sent a reference for performance purposes (a copy is generally less efficient). Nonetheless, my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The `TV` type in your `places` member expects a pointer to a `Place`.